# How to fix: Referenced AMP URL is not an AMP

Tags: amp-html

Search console added a bunch of issues with "Referenced AMP URL is not an AMP".

If I use the [AMP Test](https://search.google.com/u/1/test/amp?utm_source=gws&utm_medium=onebox&utm_campaign=suit&id=uwZYcwem5bCcgCb3A5HOkg&pageId=none) I get:

[image: Not a valid AMP page error]

However, when I check in https://validator.ampproject.org/ it shows:

[image: Validation Status: Pass]

Here is a list of some of the URLs that the Search Console says are not valid AMP pages:

- https://www.beek.io/amp/frases/satan-una-autobiografia
- https://www.beek.io/amp/frases/mi-isla
- https://www.beek.io/amp/frases/magnus-chase-y-los-dioses-de-asgard-1-la-espada-del-tiempo

I don't understand what Google expect me to fix.

Comment: Can you add how you're doing your re-direct to your AMP version? I think the re-direct may be your issue. I ran your site through the Google mobile friendly test page and it pulled down the non-AMP HTML version. This leads me to believe your re-direct may be the issue with the AMP Test. The validator only checks the HTML, the AMP Test goes a little deeper and would be affected by your re-direct which is why you validate in the validator and fail in the AMP Test.

Answer (score 1):

Going to add an answer here as well... you could try something similar to what is described on [this page](https://developers.google.com/search/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/separate-urls) which talks about mobile vs. desktop site re-directs. In particular this bit:

```
<link rel="alternate" media="only screen and (max-width: 640px)" href="http://m.example.com/page-1">
```

You have your canonical and amphtml links set-up correctly though, and the AMP Test detects the amphtml link if you run your non-AMP page through it - it's just your re-direct kills it I think. If you drop the 302 re-direct you're doing and run the AMP Test again it will probably validate.

You can probably drop the re-direct all together as Google will crawl and find the amphtml link in your header and serve that to mobile users in their search results. If you're concerned about re-directing direct visitors to your AMP version as well, then the alternate link option I linked above may be worth a shot.

Comment: Ok... I removed the redirection and tested again... That problem stopped... However, now it's worst...
It shows errors like:
- The attribute 'amp-version' may not appear in tag 'html ⚡ for top-level html'.

I believe that the validator is parsing the document in a weird way. For example the HTML tag it renders is `<html ⚡="" lang="en" amp-version="1531800879103" class="i-amphtml-singledoc i-amphtml-standalone" style="padding-top: 0px !important;">`.

It changed the `<noscript><style amp-boilerplate>...` to `<noscript>&lt;style amp-boilerplate&gt;...`

Comment: I'm testing with a staging environment. Here is a link to the test https://search.google.com/u/1/test/amp?utm_source=gws&utm_medium=onebox&utm_campaign=suit&id=nm7M4HhOsboQGzz8Vcz9Pg&pageId=none

Comment: Are you able to add your code straight from your code editor to your original post?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that I had several issues.

First I needed to correct all the links between the AMP version and the standard version of the pages.

After that, Craig Scott was right about the redirection, it was against the [Google Search guidelines for AMP](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6340290) to redirect the traffic that came from desktop or tablet.

However, I had another huge problem not directly related to the code on AMP.

We are using [Prerender](https://prerender.io/) to help crawlers read the content of our page rendered with React, but it returned an invalid version of the page to the crawler of the AMP pages.

To fix this last issue I blacklisted the AMP pages (that doesn't even use custom JS!) for prerender.

Comment: how did you blacklist the AMP page? I have the same problem.

Comment: I was using Prerenderer for Rails, so I will share how to do it on Rails, but I'm sure it must be a similar way if you're using it with another stack. You can check the documentation on how to blacklist some URLs here: https://github.com/prerender/prerender_rails#blacklist

In my case it was something like:

`config.middleware.use Rack::Prerender, blacklist: '^/amp/'`
I used that to blacklist because all my AMP pages were on the namespace `/amp/`.

I hope this helps you!