# Google is not crawling my amp links from amphtml tag when the original page is inspected

Tags: javascript, node.js, amp-html, google-search-console

My amp pages are getting served by a node.js server. However, When I tried the new Google search console feature "Inspect URL". It was unable to reach to my amp url. When I went through my logs I saw that google didn't even requested the AMP page. Can anyone help me with this?

I will add the URL too

**Original URL -** https://www.trustvardi.com/profile/eggsup

**AMP URl -** https://www.trustvardi.com/amp/profile/eggsup

The error shown in Google Search console was:

```
Referenced AMP URL is not an AMP
```

Comment: in Original URL did you add meta tag <link rel="amphtml" href="yoururl">

Comment: Hi! @BachchaSingh
Yes I did added the amphtml url and it even shows up in the page source code fetched by Google

Comment: When I check your page view source, I did not found. There is something wrong.

Comment: Hope this help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/51714008

Comment: @BachchaSingh It is a client side rendered web app and You won't see amphtml in view page source code. You can see it in Inspect Element

Comment: You'll need to insert tags like `link` server-side. This type of metadata should be visible in your source even when JavaScript is disabled.